# An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, sqlite

I am using a mac and cloud9 IDE 
every time I try and "git push heroku master"
I get this error

```
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and 
               Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'` 
               succeeds before bundling.
```

but my gem files are set up as such

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.12'
    gem 'byebug', '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
    gem 'web-console', '3.1.1'
    gem 'listen', '3.0.8'
    gem 'spring', '1.7.2'
    gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end
```

Ive also ran the

```
gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'
```

command then re-bundled then pushed to heroku master only to get the same thing

Comment: By any chance, did you make the changes in your `Gemfile` (add the `gem 'pg'`) and make sure to commit every change?

Answer (score 0):

@KLikavec,

That's because Heroku don't allow to used sqlite. He suggested our to use postgresql instead. Please refer to another thread with the same issue, and take a look at my answer. It should help you resolve the problem.

[Heroku: Failed to install gems via Bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235851/heroku-failed-to-install-gems-via-bundler/43715541#43715541)

Answer (score 0):

To do

> apt-get install libsqlite3-dev

And Run again